# Is a JSON number tied to JavaScript's Number?

Tags: javascript, java, json

Are there any limits to the size of a number in JSON? This is not JavaScript I'm talking about, but JSON.

JSON is so associated with JavaScript - but just because a number doesn't fit JavaScript's view of Number, does that make it invalid JSON?

Can JSON accommodate a Java Long for example?

Comment: On what platform / with which implementation?

Comment: there is no spec limit: a million digit number seems to be valid JSON.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - the thing that prompted the question is Elasticsearch from Java, which is Java to Java but via JSON.

Comment: Then the question becomes: can JSON parser used by Elasticsearch recognise a long in JSON (as a long can't fit in a double without a loss of precision). I don't know the answer, but it should not be hard to test if you use Elasticsearch.

Comment: @Amadan - that's what **prompted** the question. I have it working; but it got me thinking...

Comment: Working, or working well? Come on, for the record (and for science!) - If you save `9223372036854775807` do you get `9223372036854775807` back?

Comment: For the sake of science; it's a java.util.Date.getTime() into Elasticsearch. Which lots of the Java JSON libs don't parse nicely. So I started wondering; is it the lib's view of the world or, or JSON's? You answered the question perfectly. It's appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6):

> This specification allows implementations to set limits on the range
> and precision of numbers accepted.  Since software that implements
> IEEE 754-2008 binary64 (double precision) numbers [[IEEE754](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#ref-IEEE754)] is
> generally available and widely used, good interoperability can be
> achieved by implementations that expect no more precision or range
> than these provide, in the sense that implementations will
> approximate JSON numbers within the expected precision.  A JSON
> number such as `1E400` or `3.141592653589793238462643383279` may indicate
> potential interoperability problems, since it suggests that the
> software that created it expects receiving software to have greater
> capabilities for numeric magnitude and precision than is widely
> available.

> Note that when such software is used, numbers that are integers and
> are in the range `[-(2**53)+1, (2**53)-1]` are interoperable in the
> sense that implementations will agree exactly on their numeric
> values.

tl;dr: It is suggested you use numbers that are interoperable (double-precision), but not required.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON the number will be represented as a string. If the number it too large (over 53 bits i think) and you try to convert the string into a number in *JavaScript*, unexpected things will happen. However, if *Java*(or any other language that supports 64bit numbers) converts the string to an appropriate number type, you will get an expected result.